# Downloading image file in python 3 from web using selenium/urllib

Tags: python-3.x, xml, selenium, urllib

Trying to download a captcha image.

Getting following error:   urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

See code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://servicesenligne2.ville.montreal.qc.ca/sel/evalweb/index')

img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="type_recherche"]/div[5]/div/img')
src = img.get_attribute('src')

urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "captcha.png")
```

When I print src I get the following:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65317/devtools/browser/36eb75bc-f03c-41ee-96cc-138df591c665
https://servicesenligne2.ville.montreal.qc.ca/sel/evalweb/createimage.png?timestamp=1583199024767
```

Comment: Can you try to print out the value of `src`? Is that something that can be passed to `urllib.request.urlretrieve`?

Comment: @SiKing I edited the question to reflect what src returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample script that you can use to save the captcha.jpg.

```
import requests
import shutil
url = "https://servicesenligne2.ville.montreal.qc.ca/sel/evalweb/createimage.png?timestamp=1583203496087"
# we are able to use the same cookie even after refreshing (so you should be good to use the same cookie)
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=YB-eSDCWKU-SG_bKEtluH8kzvWMop4B0plLN4NOLXtO09plZSEuS!-209918963'
}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers, stream=True)
with open("captcha.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, f)
```

[image]

Below is the complete code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import shutil

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://servicesenligne2.ville.montreal.qc.ca/sel/evalweb/index')

img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="type_recherche"]/div[5]/div/img')
src = img.get_attribute('src')
jsession = driver.get_cookie('JSESSIONID')['value']
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID='+jsession
}

response = requests.get(src,headers=headers, stream=True)
with open("captcha.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, f)
```

Comment: Progress! This code allows me to download the captcha. Only issue is that when I open the file it says "it appears that we don;t support this file format"

Comment: What's the file size? If it's 0 KB then please check the cookie that is been generated for you.

Comment: Can you please try with the updated code. I am getting the `JSESSIONID` dynamically so you don't have to worry about it any more.